# Switch off wasx7303i message ("The following options are passed...") when using wsadmin in websphere AS

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

we are using wsadmin scripts to configure the websphere profile. And we configure Data sources during profile configuration, and to configure DS we pass the database password.

Problem in that the wsadmin tool printing the message wasx7303i: "The following options are passed...", with the list of passed parameters. And one of the parameters is DB pass. But it is not good for security reasons, so if there is a way to stop the wsadmin from printing this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this line in your wsadmin.properties (profile directory):

```
com.ibm.ws.scripting.echoparams=true
```

and change the value to `false`.

More settings available in wsadmin.properties:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_propscript.html

Another possibility is to use `com.ibm.ws.scripting.noechoParamNo` property as described here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK72753